# How can I get this code to recognize the dates being mentioned in this pdf? Python

Tags: python, pdf

At work, schedules are handed out with everyone's name and the shifts they're going to be working. I'm writing a code where you input your name the way it appears in the pdf document, and it spits out the shifts you're working. The way the dates are listed in the pdf, I'm having trouble getting the shifts and the dates to be returned by the code, so now all I'm getting are a bunch of shifts but no dates next to them.
Here's the code:

```
import PyPDF2

def find_work_schedule(pdf_file, employee_name):
with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as file:
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

        for page_num in range(num_pages):
            page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
            text = page.extract_text()
    
            if employee_name in text:
                start_index = text.index(employee_name)
                schedule_lines = text[start_index:].splitlines()[1:]
                schedule = []
                for line in schedule_lines:
                    if line.strip():  # Skip empty lines
                        day, *hours = line.split()
                        schedule.append((day, ' '.join(hours)))
    
                return schedule
    
    return None

# Example usage

pdf_file_path = '/Users/FrankOcean/Downloads/G Dialysis Clerks July 22.pdf'
your_name = 'Ocean, Frank'

work_schedule = find_work_schedule(pdf_file_path, your_name)

if work_schedule:
print("Your work schedule:")
for day, hours in work_schedule:
print(f"{day}: {hours}")
else:
print("Your name was not found in the PDF.")
```

I also included a picture of the schedule and the info that the code returns

[image].

[image]

I honestly am not sure what to try

Comment: You probably want a library that can parse tables e.g.`pdfplumber` https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/#extracting-tables - it also has `.extract_text(layout=True)` which you could try.